# What's broken in my rails setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to set myself up to continue work on an open source project: [KiungoWiki](https://github.com/M2i3/KiungoWiki)

A few months ago, I could simply start the the database

```
mongod
```

start the server

```
$ rails s
```

and go to localhost:3000 to see everything running normally.

Now, for some reason, things have changed. I can still start the database:

```
$ mongod

mongod --help for help and startup options
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 MongoDB starting : pid=2803 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit 
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 db version v1.6.5, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 git version: 0eb017e9b2828155a67c5612183337b89e12e291
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 sys info: Linux domU-12-31-39-06-79-A1 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Apr 13 15:09:45 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
```

But when I try starting the server, strange things happen:

```
$ rails s

Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Could not find tilt-1.3.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've tried everything the error messages suggest to no avail. Now, I would like to start understanding what the problem really is. Any help?

btw: I am trying this with the most recent code from github and it works perfectly for the other developers on the project.

**UPDATE**
I tried running

```
gem update --system
```

but got the following result:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
ERROR:  gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

Even `gem --version` spews out errors

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mongo-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55abbd6c78> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-15 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/bson_ext-1.6.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55ab9b6d08> 1.6.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f55aba7e290> 3.0.7"]
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/orm_adapter-0.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
1.7.2
```

**UPDATE** Problem changed

Following @Andreas' suggestions, I deleted my gem folder and re-installed everything

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
rvm requirements
rvm reload
gedit .bashrc &
rvm reinstall 1.9.2
rvm gemset create rails3
rvm 1.9.2@rails3 gem update --system
rvm 1.9.2@rails3 gem install rails --version 3.1.1
cd Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki
bundle install
```

No errors whatsoever. `mongod` works fine, but `rails s` says:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: Change Factory.define to FactoryGirl.define
Exiting
/home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:6:in `define': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/deprecated.rb:5:in `method_missing'
    from /home/shawn/Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki/spec/factories/albums.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:26:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/shawn/Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/shawn/Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/shawn/Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/shawn/Documents/Projets/KiungoWiki/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your gem folder and update rubygems, then reinstall the gems.

Comment: That certainly got things moving. see edit. I'll probably end up moving the rest of my progress to a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to upgrade RubyGems:

```
gem update --system
```

and then run `bundle install` again.

Comment: What's the output of `gem --version`? Did you try to update RubyGems through apt-get like the error message suggested?

Comment: `gem --version` generates more errors (see edit), then says `1.7.2`. `sudo apt-get install rubygems` says `rubygems is already the newest version.`

Comment: RubyGems is well into version 1.8 these days. Have you run `apt-get update` and/or `apt-get upgrade` to make sure your local package index is up-to-date?

Comment: I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but `gem --versions` still outputs the same thing...

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you. Your version of RubyGems needs to be updated to parse the new spec format, so you may have to force the update like it says in the error message.